# Inserting into NVARCHAR column type using PHP Oracle

Tags: php, database, oracle

I want to save all unicode data in a column which is defined as `nvarchar` like this in oracle database  :

> "आवस्यकता है ड्राइवर्स की पूर्ण विवरण के साथ संपर्क करें - यादव
>   (8000000008)"

but when i run my insert query i get in column which is a `nvarchar` type
in database.

> ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿ ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿ - ¿¿¿¿
>   (8000000008)

So my Question is -> How to save data for a column which has `nvarchar` datatype using `php` `oracle`?

Here is what i am trying to do-

```
putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1");
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=//u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib");
$conn = oci_connect('db1', 'ps1', '//xxx.xx.xx.xx:1521/orcl', 'AL32UTF8') or die('db not connected');

     $stmt=oci_parse($conn,"INSERT INTO TABLENM (VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 )  VALUES (:VAL1, :VAL2, :VAL3, :VAL4,  :VAL5 )");
     $VAL1 = "JK";
     $VAL2 = "10005072";
     $VAL3 = "27-JUL-17";
     $VAL4 = 1;
     $VAL5 = "आवस्यकता है ड्राइवर्स की पूर्ण विवरण के साथ संपर्क करें - यादव (8000000008)"; // VAL5 is created with datatype nvarchar in database
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':VAL1', $VAL1, 1000);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':VAL2', $VAL2, 1000);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':VAL3', $VAL3, 1000);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':VAL4', $VAL4, 1000);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':VAL5', $VAL5, 1000, SQLT_LBI);


     $RES =   oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
     oci_commit($conn);
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($RES);
```

I found this `SQLT_LBI` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#itemizedlist), but its not working for me.

Is there any chances to get this Done?

Please help!

Comment: Explain how it is "not working". Add errors and all details that may help people to answer your question.

Comment: Don't use `SQLT_LBI`.  As described on the PHP manual page you linked that is "for LONG RAW columns". `NVARCHAR` is a character(unicode) datatype.

Comment: OK. but i can't find anything for `NVARCHAR` on that ist. So what should i do to save that kind of data?

Comment: As I wrote, it's character data.  So either nothing, since the default is `SQLT_CHR`, or explicitly `SQLT_CHR`.

Comment: Try to add `putenv("NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8");` - note the dot before "AL32UTF8"

Comment: Did you save the php-script as UTF-8? (check editor settings)

Comment: Yes my script is saved in UTF-8.. and i will try `NLS_LANG`.. i have tried that but it was without dot (.)

Comment: Pro tip: never set Oracle environment variables in scripts with putenv() since this may not be read if the process has already initialized, e.g. when using persistent connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither PHP OCI8 or PDO_OCI support NVARCHAR, NCHAR or NCLOB types. Page 149 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html is still valid as of now:

> Oracle's NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, and NCLOB types are not supported in the
>   OCI8 extension

There may be some odd environments where it works (?), but that might be only where the DB character set width is big enough to hold the DB national character set.