# oci_bind_by_name not working when unescaped works

Tags: php, oracle

Working on an UPDATE query for an Oracle database. The field in question is of the type `NCHAR(25)`, which accepts a 25 character `UTF-8` byte string. My input values are in `ASCII` which should work no problem.

The following snippet uses the `oci_bind_by_name` function to escape the variable in the WHERE clause and insert into the placeholder variable `:herp`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET OPT = '1' WHERE FIELD = :herp";
$stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":herp", $record['value'], -1, SQLT_CHR);
```

This next snippet does not use the `oci_bind_by_name` function and instead inserts the variable into the SQL statement **unescaped** (YOLO).

```
$sql = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET OPT = '1' WHERE FIELD = '".$record['value']."'";
$stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
```

### My problem

The first snippet does not work, while the second one works fine, i.e. the UPDATE statement succeeds every time on the second method while it fails every time on the first.

Both versions of the `UPDATE` should work. However when I use the `oci_bind_by_name` function for a few fields, somehow the variable is getting changed. (I am doing more rigorous error checking in the actual code).

### My question

What is going on here? How can I still use the `oci_bind_by_name` instead of just concatenating the variable directly into the SQL statement?

Comment: PHP OCI8 doesn't have support for NCHAR, NVARCHAR etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369299/how-to-save-data-for-a-column-which-has-nvarchar-datatype-using-php-oracle

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks for the link. I think I am going to build the query by hand and hope for the best in production (no user input handled). The lack of support for NCHAR is pretty crippling tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369299/how-to-save-data-for-a-column-which-has-nvarchar-datatype-using-php-oracle):

> Neither PHP OCI8 or PDO_OCI support NVARCHAR, NCHAR or NCLOB types.