# Ñ characters not saving/showing in columns in PHP 7/PROPEL2.0/Oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, propel

Im newbie using Propel ORM and specially Oracle, cause im used in MYSQL

The Ñ in database(Oracle11g) not showing when I'm saving or querying in PROPEL ORM 2.0

The column type in Oracle is NVARCHAR2

[Here is the data in oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYJkT.png)

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKePN.png)

Pls help. Im so depressed :(.
I've been finding solutions for this issue for a month.
Thank you very much

Comment: I am no database expert, someone else can chime in on Oracle specifics. Looking at this there's an issue with string encoding. Either that column is ASCII and you're trying to add Unicode characters or maybe you're adding ascii to a unicode column? Either way, you'll find the answer by seeing where in your code flow it is or is not encoding the string correctly.

Comment: i think PROPEL ORM is causing this. i hope theres a PROPEL ORM expert here that can help me. Propel's community is not that big

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Oracle drivers don't have good support for the NVARCHAR or NCLOB types (see questions like [Inserting into NVARCHAR column type using PHP Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369299/inserting-into-nvarchar-column-type-using-php-oracle)).

The solution is to stop using NVARCHAR2 columns.  Use a DB with base character set of AL32UTF8 and put your data in VARCHAR2 columns.   You can check the base character set of the DB by running `SELECT value AS db_charset FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

Also make sure you are initializing PHP with the correct "client side" character set, e.g. like `$dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/orclpdb;charset=AL32UTF8', ... );`

Comment: may I ask sir if is it possible to change character set for our existing db right now? we're using oracle 11g

Comment: See doc like https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-162F0087-2F35-424B-8033-1820828150E5 (but check what is available 11g documentation)